# mutual inductance of BLDC motor

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, mutual-inductance

I want to use BLDC motor for charging the E-rickshaw for that I need to find the parameters of the motor. I have measured the Resistance and self-inductance of the motor but I am facing difficulties regarding finding the mutual inductance of the motor.
So I want to know What technique can be used to find the mutual inductance of motor for all three phases?

Comment: Why do you need to know the net mutual inductance of the three phases when trying to determine the efficiency of charging something?

Comment: I am not determining the efficiency of charging rather I am trying to use BLDC for charging the batteries using machine windings as mutually coupled inductors (Interleaved boost converter) so I need to find the exact parameter values hence I have to find the mutual inductance.

Comment: Are you proposing to use the motor "_as an inductor_", or are you proposing to drive the motor (i.e: down a hill)?

Comment: I am trying to use the motor as an inductor to charge the battery when the vehicle is stationary.

Comment: See if [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/408234/mutual-inductance-vs-coupling-coefficient?answertab=votes#tab-top) helps you